# How to turn off IP Masquerade in flannel

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, flannel

In my Kubernetes cluster I couldn't connect to the internet from my Containers. So after searching, I found a possible solution, that is to turn off "IP Masquerade". But I had no luck turning this off. Whatever I did I cannot get it disabled.

First I change the following,

```
/etc/kubernetes/cni/docker_opts_cni.env

DOCKER_OPT_BIP=""
DOCKER_OPT_IPMASQ="false"
```

Then tried

```
/etc/kubernetes/cni/docker_opts_cni.env

DOCKER_OPT_BIP=""
DOCKER_OPT_IPMASQ="--ip-masq=false"
```

I'm using the latest Kubernetes version(v 1.6.3) and I have followed [this](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html) to configure my cluster. I'm using flannel without calico. Can someone guide me on how I can get this disabled? Thanks in advance/

Answer (score 2):

This is an example configuration for creating new flannel network using cni for docker.

```
/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conf

{
    "cniVersion": "0.2.0",
    "name": "mybridge",
    "type": "bridge",
    "bridge": "cni_bridge1",
    "isGateway": true,
    "ipMasq": true,
    "ipam": {
        "type": "host-local",
        "subnet": "10.15.30.0/24",
        "routes": [
            { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" },
            { "dst": "1.1.1.1/32", "gw":"10.15.30.1"}
        ],
        "rangeStart": "10.15.30.100",
        "rangeEnd": "10.15.30.200",
        "gateway": "10.15.30.99"
    }
}
```

In your configuration file changing `ipMasq` value for `true` to `false` or adding the option if not present should turn off "IP Masquerade"

Answer (score 0):

Just a clarification, by flannel with calico do you mean [canal](https://github.com/projectcalico/canal) ?

If so there is an option to flip in the configuration [here](https://github.com/projectcalico/canal/blob/d5a9fd2e63d41b6e91aa389f965cf9c002f9c8c3/k8s-install/canal.yaml#L15).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had a typo in my question, I wanted to say "without calico" I have modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

remove command line Opts "--ip-masq"